# Get and Post nested classes with a Web API

Tags: c#, .net, api, server

I am learning how to create a web API Server using .net
For now I am using the following guide, and made it work same as they show on their examples:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio
Now, I wanted to change the structure of my model, and add a nested class inside of it, with the following structure:

```
public class Element1
{    
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }    
    public TodoItem element2 { get; set; }
}

public class TodoItem
{    
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
}
```

When I use the Post method with this structure using Postman, i get the correct data:

```
{
    "name": "A Name",
    "element2 ":
    {
        "title":"Title",
        "content ": "content"
    }
}
```

But, when I try to use the Get method, the content from the nested class is always `Null`:

```
{
    "name": "A Name",
    "element2 ": NULL
}
```

I am not sure why this is happening, may be that the methods used on the provided guide do not support these structures. There is a way to modify it to do so?

Bellow are the method from the controller that i did according to the guide I provided before:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Element1>> GetElement1(long id)
{
    var element = await _context.GetElement1.FindAsync(id);

    if (element == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return element ;
}


[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Element1>> PostElement1(Element1 element1)
{
    _context.TodoItems.Add(element1);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetElement1), new { id = element1.Id }, element1);
}
```

I am just starting and learn so i may have made a mistake or missing something pretty basic :)
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Is lazy loading enabled in the dbContext?  - If it isn't then it will only load the requested entity and not any navigational properties. You could try to use .Include() to explicitly include the nested property.

Comment: Probably showing EF Config will help.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that element2 is not saved at all in the database, because the Element1 class needs a foreign key for element2:

```
public class Element1
{    
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }   
   public int element2Id { get; set; } 
   public virtual TodoItem element2 { get; set; }
}
```

Also, the virtual keyword will enable the lazy loading for the linked class